# SwiftUI: Status bar color for specific view

Tags: swiftui

I have a specific view in my application where I need the status bar to be white (dark mode).

I've tried setting the `.preferredColorScheme(.dark)` but as the documentation mentions, that affects all the views in my window which is not what I'm looking for.

I've taken a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59569503/swiftui-set-status-bar-color-for-a-specific-view) but it seems to be done using SceneDelgate which I am not making use of.

Is there any workaround to this?

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 16, you can set `.toolbarColorScheme` for a specific View. Unfortunately, this is not supported on older iOS Versions. As a workaround that does not involve `SceneDelegate`, you could manipulate `UIToolBar.appearance()` directly with a new tint color. This has nothing to do with the preferred color scheme (e.g., light or dark mode), but could have the same effect.