# Can not override the preferredStatusBarStyle

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uistatusbar

In dark mode style, the status bar disappear cause of dark color.

I added the:

```
 override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
            return .lightContent
        }
```

but the problem is, when I add the method in `"viewDidLoad"` I get the error:

> override can only be specified in class member

any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change Status Bar text color in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios)

Comment: Also, check your syntax, you might have a missing '}'

Comment: Thank you but the links didn't answer my question. and I checked the  syntax, it is not missing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am going to answer the question here, maybe it can help someone else:

After hours checking my codes, I found out that I have rootViewController which I used as a authentication then after the authentication user pass to TabbarViewController... which is not rootViewController, I added the:

> preferredStatusBarStyle

To my rootViewController and it works.

> View controller-based status bar appearance should be
> YES

Answer (score -1):

`preferredStatusBarStyle` is a member of the `UIViewController` class. What you want to do here is to override this class member. The snippet in your question have nothing to do in the `viewDidLoad` method and should be placed in your subclass body like this :

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Comment: Bu it won't call the preferredStatusBarStyle.

Comment: `preferredStatusBarStyle` is called by UIKit.

Comment: I tried before writing the question, it doesnt work.

Comment: Did you set the `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` value in your .plist ? Did you call the `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` method in the `viewDidLoad` as suggested in the linked question ?

Comment: View controller-based status bar appearance = NO, and  called setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate() and it didn't work.

Comment: `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` should be set to YES if you are overriding it in your viewController.