# iOS: Specify status bar text color when using UINavigationBarAppearance now barstyle is ignored

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

## Problem

I have an app that has different colour navigation bars for different flows. Some navigation bars have a light background and require black status bar text. Others have a darker navigation bar and require white status bar text.

As part of the move to iOS15 I have updated an app I am working on to use the `UINavigationBarAppearance` approach to navigation bar styling.
I am able to style everything as I could before other than the status bar color.

Previously I have been using the `barStyle` property on navigation bar to set the status bar text color.

```
navigationBar.barStyle = .black
```

This does not appear to work when using  `UINavigationBarAppearance`.

## Sample code

**Old styling approach**

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar
        
        // Style using old approach
        navigationBar?.barTintColor = UIColor.purple
        navigationBar?.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        
        // Use barStyle to set status bar text color to white
        // This only work when using the old styling approach
        navigationBar?.barStyle = .black
    }
```

[image]

**New styling approach**

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar
        
        // Style nav bar using new Appearance API
        let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
        navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]

        navigationBar?.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
        navigationBar?.scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance
        
        // Use barStyle to set status bar text color to white
        // This only work when using the old styling approach
        navigationBar?.barStyle = .black
    }
```

[image]

## Alternatives

**Force dark/light mode on the navigation bar**

It is possible to make the status bar text white using the property `overrideUserInterfaceStyle`. To make the status bar text white, set

```
navigationBar.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = dark
```

However, this results in menus from buttons in the nav bar in dark mode too which is not what I want.

[image]

**Subclass UINavigationController**

I imagine I could also subclass UINavigationController and explicitly override the `preferredStatusBarStyle` to force black or white text.

Having to use a subclass everywhere we make new navigation controllers just to specify the status bar text color seems a bit extreme.

**Anything else?**

I'm not sure if there is a better approach to this?

Comment: Thank you for posting this and clearly describing the problem! We are encountering these exact same issues! I will let you know if we find a solution.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solutions to this one by any chance?

Comment: I have been struggling with it for past couple hours and it looks like the system is trying to match status bar color to navbar's tint color. When I set it to white, status bar is white, if I set it to some random color, it is black. At least that's how it works in my case, there might be other things involved.

Comment: Any updates? facing the same issue :(

Answer (score 4):

I was able to set the status bar text white using:

```
navController.navigationBar.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
```

Note that bencallis, the creator of this question, warns that this solution "results in menus from buttons in the nav bar in dark mode too which is not what I want". I don't use menus like this so that is not a problem for me. Maybe it's not for you too.

Answer (score 3):

I use both barStyle and overrideUserInterfaceStyle with UINavigationBarAppearance

```
// statusBarStyle is .black or .default
if case .black = statusBarStyle {
     navigationController?.navigationBar.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
} else {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
}
navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = statusBarStyle
```

See how it works:

[image]
[image]

Comment: This solution works fine. If you use only `navigationController?.navigationBar.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark` then it's not working.