# Is there a way to control the Status Bar color with Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I'm currently trying to build an app, but for some reason iOS isn't registering the status bar color as white. I'm wondering how I can set it as a certain color using only JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Related?  [How to change status bar colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios)