# iPhone's Top Bar is the Wrong Color

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, ipados

The top bar (the bar at the very top of the device's screen with the time, battery, WiFi, etc.) in my iOS app is the same color as the background color, making it invisible.
Usually, the device automatically sets the bar color based on the background color, but this time it isn’t.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbLRH.jpg) is a photo of the problem.

I can tell it is not hidden because when there is an alert presented, and the background is slightly dimmed, [the top bar is visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axKxv.jpg).

Is there a way to set this directly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change Status Bar text color in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios)

Comment: Just tried it, didn’t work, thanks.

Comment: `Just tried it, didn’t work, thanks.` What have you tried? What did not work? Please add the code to your question so we can see what´s going on.